# what is difference between Social Configurer Adapter and Social Configurer?

Tags: spring, spring-social

what is difference between Social Configurer Adapter and Social Configurer ?

Social Configurer is interface.
Social Configurer is abstractclass.

I do not know what the difference is for both.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that SocialConfigurerAdapter  gives a standard implementation for the methods declared in the SocialConfigurer interface. Thus when you extend SocialConfigurerAdapter you are not obligated to override the methods of SocialConfigurer anymore since the adapter class has already provided it with a standard implementation.

See the code of SocialConfigurerAdapter

```
public abstract class SocialConfigurerAdapter implements SocialConfigurer {
    public SocialConfigurerAdapter() {
    }

    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer connectionFactoryConfigurer, Environment environment) {
    }

    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
        return null;
    }

    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        return new InMemoryUsersConnectionRepository(connectionFactoryLocator);
    }
}
```